# `X-Forwarded-For` is not used by ASP.Net Core behind reverse proxy

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am trying to **get the remote IP address** of a request (i.e., the IP of the client who sent the request) in my **ASP.Net Core 2.1** MVC Controller (runs in .Net Docker container). Taking into consideration that My ASP.Net Core application **is located behind NGINX reverse proxy** (runs in NGINX Docker container).

As known, when the reverse proxy redirects the request to my .Net Core application, it will change the source IP of my request (TCP/IP layer), therefore, I configured NGINX to add `X-Forwarded-For` with the original IP to the request. The request that is redirected from NGINX container to .Net container has `X-Forwarded-For` in the header:

[image]

And of course, I configured .Net Core to know about that:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    // Rewrite the header when being redirected (this is required because we are behind reverse proxy)
    var forwardedHeadersOptions = new ForwardedHeadersOptions
    {
        ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto,
        KnownProxies = { IPAddress.Parse("172.20.10.2"), IPAddress.Parse("172.20.10.3"), IPAddress.Parse("172.20.10.4") },
    };

    forwardedHeadersOptions.KnownNetworks.Add(
        new IPNetwork(IPAddress.Parse("172.0.0.0"), 8));
    forwardedHeadersOptions.KnownNetworks.Add(
        new IPNetwork(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 8));

    app.UseForwardedHeaders(forwardedHeadersOptions);
    ...
```

However, `HTTPContext.Connection.RemoteIPAddress` still returning 172.20.10.3 (NGINX container IP, not the real remote IP):

```
logger.LogDebug("Remote IP Address: " + Request.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.ToString());
```

> Remote IP Address: 172.20.10.3

I checked my header in .Net Core, it has `X-Forwarded-For` with the correct original remote IP address:

```
logger.LogDebug("X-Forwarded-For Header Feature: " + HttpContext.Request.Headers["X-Forwarded-For"]);
```

> X-Forwarded-For Header Feature: 85.XX.4.121

Does someone have any idea what I am missing? Why RemoteIPAddress still returning the IP of the NGINX docker container instead of the real remote IP address?

#### Update

My `Program.cs`

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BuildWebHost(args).Run();
    }

    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseUrls("http://*:5000")
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();
}
```

I tried Also to configure the the `ForwarededHeadersOptions` by configuring its service like this:

```
services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options =>
{
    options.ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto;
    //options.KnownNetworks.Add(new IPNetwork(IPAddress.Parse("172.0.0.0"), 8));
    options.RequireHeaderSymmetry = false;
    options.ForwardLimit = null;
    options.KnownProxies.Add(IPAddress.Parse("172.20.10.3"));
    //options.KnownNetworks.Add(new IPNetwork(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 8));
});
```

With no success...

#### UPDATE 2

OK I guess I am on the right way, the IP address returned by `RemoteIPAddress` was ::ffff:172.20.10.20, not 172.20.10.20! I did not know that they are different. The [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/proxy-load-balancer?view=aspnetcore-2.1) helped me to discover that.

Comment: Do you have multiple `X-Forwarded-For` headers when it arrives at your application? iirc by default, the **first** `X-Forwarded-For` will be used when found by default. Also please make sure, you can set `ForwardLimit` to `null` to remove the limit, but only if `KnowProxies` and `KnownNetworks`  is set (as in your case): https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.forwardedheadersoptions.forwardlimit?view=aspnetcore-2.1. By Default `ForwardLimit` is set to 1, so it will only process the **FIRST** entry, which may be an issue in case you have multiple proxies...

Comment: ...where each proxy sets its own headers

Comment: @Tseng, I already tried setting `ForwardLimit` to `null`, but unfortunately with no success, I have only one reverse proxy, and one `X-Forwarded-For` in my header (shown in pictures). I have no more ideas what that could be... Totally strange...

Comment: Also note that the `UseIISIntegration` call in Programm.cs, in the default platforms **also** registers the `UseForwardedHeaders` (or used to) middleware though. Try instead of using `UseForwardedHeader` a `services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options => ...)` within your ConfigureServices, then you won't have two middlewares by accident and can be sure that your configuration is used in the correct middleware, since its resolved via DI, see https://github.com/aspnet/IISIntegration/blob/2.1.2/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration/WebHostBuilderIISExtensions.cs#L89-L92

Comment: @Tseng, I also tried that, with no success... I added a small update to the question

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The IP I got from `RemoteIPAddress` was IPv4 represented as IPv6 (was ::ffff:172.20.10.20, not 172.20.10.20!). I was using only IPv4 part of the IP, therefore the `KnownProxies` in my case were wrong. I should have entered the full IPv4 address also with the v6 representation part.

The official documentation showed that:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/proxy-load-balancer?view=aspnetcore-2.1

###### UPDATE as requested by a comment:

So in my case, the code should look like this:

```
services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options =>
{
    options.ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto;
    options.RequireHeaderSymmetry = false;
    options.ForwardLimit = null;
    options.KnownProxies.Add(IPAddress.Parse("::ffff:172.20.10.20")); // <<-- Notice the full format of the IP address.
});
```

Comment: Can you tell us what you did `options.KnownProxies.Add(IPAddress.Parse("::ffff:172.20.10.20"));`

Comment: @user960567 sorry I did not understand your question?

Comment: I what code should you used to fix the issue?

Comment: @user960567 I updated the answer to show you the enhanced code.

Comment: Thanks. In my case I also needed to update ForwardLimit.

Answer (score 11):

As per the official documentation, if you are using **Apache or Nginx integration**, following code should be added to the `Startup.ConfigureServices` method.

```
// using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpOverrides;

    services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | 
            ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto;
        // Only loopback proxies are allowed by default.
        // Clear that restriction because forwarders are enabled by explicit 
        // configuration.
        options.KnownNetworks.Clear();
        options.KnownProxies.Clear();
    });
```

and then on top of everything, in `Configure` method use

```
app.UseForwardedHeaders();
```

Further suppose in nginx conf file, inside a location, use

```
proxy_set_header   Host $host;
proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
```

Now the first entry in the `X-Forwarded-For` will be the real client IP.

**IMPORTANT:** If you want to secure the app and not allow an attacker inject X-Forwarded-For, Please read this [answer](https://serverfault.com/a/414166/523988).

Please see [Forward the scheme for Linux and non-IIS reverse proxies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/proxy-load-balancer?view=aspnetcore-2.1#forward-the-scheme-for-linux-and-non-iis-reverse-proxies-1),  [Configure Nginx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-nginx?view=aspnetcore-2.1#configure-nginx) and [Dealing with invalid headers](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/forwarded/#dealing-with-invalid-headers)